# kuubuntu 23.10 , glxinfo opengl render not show nvidia

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, wayland, opengl

I have two graphics cards, the monitor is connect to HDMI on nvidia card.  I noticed UI slowness I suspect it's related?

I am using wayland, lspci show nvidia driver is used.

```
(base) ➜  ~ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

wayland
(base) ➜  ~ uname -a
Linux x11 6.5.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Oct  7 01:35:40 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) ➜  ~ lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family [1a03:2000] (rev 30)
        Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc ASPEED Graphics Family [15d9:0728]
        Kernel driver in use: ast
--
81:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] [10de:1e07] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Shenzhen Colorful Yugong Technology and Development Co. TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] [7377:120b]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

nvidia driver is installed.

```
(base) ➜  ~ nvidia-smi 
Mon Oct 16 01:06:16 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.113.01             Driver Version: 535.113.01   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti     Off | 00000000:81:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   47C    P8              22W / 250W |     54MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1548      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           20MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

however, glxinfo is showing llvmpipe.

```
(base) ➜  ~ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
```

Answer (score 0):

after a few rounds with chatgpt, the problem is solved.

I need to create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` with content

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Nvidia Card"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:129:0:0"  # Replace with your actual PCI BusID
EndSection
```

One thing to notice here is the PCI busID should be in decimal, but lspci will show a hex number. For example on my host lspci output is 81. hex(81) == dec(129)

```
81:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A] (rev a1)
```

The easiest way is probably just use the value `nvidia-xconfig`generated.

I still don't really get the reason why `nvidia-xconfig` don't just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing "libnvidia-egl-wayland1"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mir-team/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnvidia-egl-wayland1
```

To revert this change use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mir-team/dev
```

***OS**: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64,
**Gnome version**: 45.1,
**Windowing system**: Wayland,
**kernel version**: Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic,
**GPU**: NVIDIA Quadro P3200 Mobile*

```
inxi -Gx |grep API
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.129.03 renderer: Quadro P3200 with Max-Q
```